# How to configure react native android library to use npm installed react-native?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm writing an android library, need to call ReactInstanceManager.onHostResume, my build.gradle file content is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
}
```

I installed it into an example project with `npm install --save react-native-mylib`, and then compile the project with `react-native run-android`, some errors caused:

```
MyModuleActivity.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
      mReactInstanceManager.onHostPause();
                           ^
  symbol:   method onHostPause()
  location: variable mReactInstanceManager of type ReactInstanceManager
```

I try to find installed react-native libraries:

```
find . -iname "*.jar"
...
./node_modules/react-native-mylib/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.20.1/jars/classes.jar
./node_modules/react-native-mylib/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.20.1/jars/libs/infer-annotations-1.5.jar
...
```

Seems it installed react-native@0.20.1 from maven, this version of react-native hasn't onHostPause method.

**EDIT:**

Find libraries in another project that linked some libraries, they are all linked old version of react-native:

```
$ find . -iname "*.jar" | grep com.facebook.react
./android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.25.1/jars/classes.jar
./android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.25.1/jars/libs/infer-annotations-1.5.jar
./android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.26.0/jars/classes.jar
./android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.26.0/jars/libs/infer-annotations-1.5.jar
./node_modules/react-native/android/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.26.0/react-native-0.26.0-javadoc.jar
./node_modules/react-native/android/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.26.0/react-native-0.26.0-sources.jar
./node_modules/react-native-android-blurryoverlay/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.16.1/jars/classes.jar
./node_modules/react-native-android-blurryoverlay/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.16.1/jars/libs/infer-annotations-1.5.jar
./node_modules/react-native-applean/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.20.1/jars/classes.jar
./node_modules/react-native-applean/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.20.1/jars/libs/infer-annotations-1.5.jar
./node_modules/react-native-applean-appview/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.20.1/jars/classes.jar
./node_modules/react-native-applean-appview/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.20.1/jars/libs/infer-annotations-1.5.jar
./node_modules/react-native-barcodescanner/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.19.1/jars/classes.jar
./node_modules/react-native-barcodescanner/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.19.1/jars/libs/infer-annotations-1.5.jar
./node_modules/react-native-camera/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.19.1/jars/classes.jar
./node_modules/react-native-camera/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.19.1/jars/libs/infer-annotations-1.5.jar
./node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.19.1/jars/classes.jar
./node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.19.1/jars/libs/infer-annotations-1.5.jar
./node_modules/react-native-device-info/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.11.0/jars/classes.jar
./node_modules/react-native-device-info/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.11.0/jars/libs/infer-annotations-1.5.jar
./node_modules/react-native-fs/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.12.0/jars/classes.jar
./node_modules/react-native-fs/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.12.0/jars/libs/infer-annotations-1.5.jar
./node_modules/react-native-mipush/android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.20.1/jars/classes.jar
./node_modules/react-native-mipush/android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.20.1/jars/libs/infer-annotations-1.5.jar
./node_modules/react-native-orientation/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.11.0/jars/classes.jar
./node_modules/react-native-orientation/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.11.0/jars/libs/infer-annotations-1.5.jar
./node_modules/react-native-sound/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.11.0/jars/classes.jar
./node_modules/react-native-sound/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.11.0/jars/libs/infer-annotations-1.5.jar
./node_modules/react-native-sound/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.12.0/jars/classes.jar
./node_modules/react-native-sound/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.12.0/jars/libs/infer-annotations-1.5.jar
./node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.20.1/jars/classes.jar
./node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.20.1/jars/libs/infer-annotations-1.5.jar
./node_modules/react-native-vibration/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.12.0/jars/classes.jar
./node_modules/react-native-vibration/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.12.0/jars/libs/infer-annotations-1.5.jar
```

**Question: How to configure it to use node_modules/react-native/android correctly?**

**EDIT: Resolved, just set correct repositories to:**

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$projectDir/../../../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved a while ago as well...
I created a library using [react-native-create-library](https://github.com/frostney/react-native-create-library).
The latest version maven provides is 0.20.1, which is a little old for today's react-native versions. So I installed the RN version I needed into the node_modules folder of my library

> npm install react-native@0.46.1

And in build.gradle

```
repositories {
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
    jcenter()
}
//
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
}
```

This way you don't need to keep your library inside of your master project in order to build and check your syntax.