# Can't build apk after editing build gradle

Tags: android, react-native

I had some compatibility issues with some latest APIs version so i had to downgrade  compileSdkVersion and
targetSdkVersion of build.gradle , it solved my compatibility issues , APP work fine , but when i try to generate apk it fails 
it says :

> error: invalid file path
>   '/Users/mac/Documents/forgetmenot/node_modules/react-native-camera/android/build/intermediates/manifests/aapt/release/AndroidManifest.xml'.

edited : 
here gradle build code :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 26
        targetSdkVersion = 24
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}



could you please help
```

Comment: Can you please share your code? like the gradle. we cant help if we do not know what was the changes

Comment: Possible duplicate -> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361004/how-to-configure-react-native-android-library-to-use-npm-installed-react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361004/how-to-configure-react-native-android-library-to-use-npm-installed-react-native)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure react native android library to use npm installed react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361004/how-to-configure-react-native-android-library-to-use-npm-installed-react-native)